# Triggering a jquery slidedown message on redirect

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I have a list of links of twitter accounts (on people.php) a user can follow by pressing the persons name.  When they press the link the follow.php script is run and the user is following the person.  At the end of this script there is a header("Location:people.php") redirecting the user back to the people page.

What I want to do is give the user a message when they are redirected to the people.php page in a slide down message saying they are now following whatever person they clicked on.

I understand how to make this (this is what I am going to make http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wNz5T8SepQ), I just don't know how to connect it so the slide down message is triggered only on this redirect, not when the user first visits the people.php page, and how to make it so the message say which person you just followed.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are controlling the redirect, can you append a variable on the query string that will force a notification, ala:
http://www.yoursite.com/people.php?notify=true

You might also use a session cookie.  Set the cookie when the user click the link  and remove it when the message displays.  Since you'll be using jQuery, you can use the jQ cookie plugin for simplicity:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

change your redirect header to include an extra flag - header("Location:people.php?following=who")  and then you can look for that param when they return to the people.php page after following someone